# Rotativa ActionAsPdf background-image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, rotativa

I'm using Rotativa ActionAsPDF to create a PDF of a view, but the background-image property won't work.  However, it does work if I return the Action as a regular view.

ReportController:

```
public ActionResult CertificateAsPdf(int courseid, string type, int owningmtuid, int? attendeeid, int? agencyid, int? canineCertificationId)
{
    return new ActionAsPdf("Certificate", new { courseid = courseid, type = type, attendeeid = attendeeid, owningmtuid = owningmtuid, agencyid = agencyid, canineCertificationId = canineCertificationId })
    {
        FileName = "Certificate.pdf",
        PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Landscape,
    };
}

public ActionResult Certificate(int courseid, string type, int owningmtuid, int? attendeeid, int? agencyid, int? canineCertificationId)
{
    // Logic to get data
    return View("MTUCertificate", model);
}
```

MTUCertificateView:

```
<style>
    .mtulogo {
        background-image: url("@Url.Action("getimage", "mtu", new { area = "dataadministration", path = Model.MTULogoImage })");
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 200px;
    }
</style>
```

The issue I'm having is the background image isn't loading.  The path parameter Model.MTULogoImage has a UNC saved in the database formatted like \\ipaddress\websitename\logos\mtulogo.png

GetImage Action:

```
public ActionResult GetImage(string path)
{
    string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(Path.GetFileName(path));
    return File(@path, contentType);
}
```

Again, if I return just a regular View I have no issues, it's when I change it to `return new ActionAsPDF` when I start to have issues.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting this fixed by converting the UNC path to bytes.

Updated Action:

```
public ActionResult Certificate(int courseid, string type, int owningmtuid, int? attendeeid, int? agencyid, int? canineCertificationId)
{
    //mtu.MTULogoImage below formatted like \\ipaddress\websitename\logos\mtulogo.png
    model.MTULogoImage = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(mtu.MTULogoImage);
    model.MTULogoImageContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(Path.GetFileName(mtu.MTULogoImage));

    return View("MTUCertificate", model);
}
```

Updated View:

```
.mtulogo {
    background-image: url(@string.Format("data:{0};base64,{1}", Model.MTULogoImageContentType, Convert.ToBase64String(Model.MTULogoImage)));
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 200px;
}
```